# Make API call with body parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm make an API call like so...(and it is working fine)

```
let url1 = URL(string: "https://clodsso.company.com/oauth2/access_token?AccessManagement")!
                var request = URLRequest(url: url1)
                request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
                let session = URLSession.shared
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                let bodyStr = "grant_type=password&client_id=ASDH_HG&client_secret=768HJGLJfgfo879&username=A123456&password=passwordhyuhg&scope=shjDGH"

                request.httpBody = bodyStr.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue), allowLossyConversion: true)

                let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        return
                    }
                    guard let data = data else {
                        return
                    }

                    do {

                        //create json object from data
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {

                            print("Success resp :- \(json)")
                            // handle json...

                        }

                    } catch let error {

                        print("Failure resp : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }

  })
  task.resume()
```

Now I want to make an API call that has a couple of body parameters namely accessToken and Refresh token. It is given in the body (in POSTMAN) like so,

```
{
    "AccessToken":"hbvshiuevbkvbjdvkejbvk",
    "RefreshToken":"sfuhksdjfksjdhfksjdhf"
}
```

Now how can I make an API call in such a case when I have body parameters also..? Is it similar to the normal API call I gave above..?

Comment: Use JSONSerialization to create the JSON Data ;)

Comment: Use an collection of key-value pair (`[String:Any]`) instead of a string, and use the JSONSerialization to convert that to `httpBody` data. `request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyParams)` where `bodyParams`is an `[String:Any]` dictonary

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the solution to what you want.

```swift
let body: [String : Any] = ["AccessToken" : "hbvshiuevbkvbjdvkejbvk", "RefreshToken" : "sfuhksdjfksjdhfksjdhf"]
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .prettyPrinted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply prepare your params, convert them into **Data** using **JSONSerialization** and pass that data to **httpBody** of **URLRequest**. You can use following sample of code into your project:

```
let params: [String: Any] = ["AccessToken": "hbvshiuevbkvbjdvkejbvk", "RefreshToken": "sfuhksdjfksjdhfksjdhf"]

guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}

request.httpBody = data
```